# Why is the explicit tabindex of elements added to the DOM after page load not being honored?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-isotope, section508

I've got an Angular 4 app where content is loaded within a component.  This content uses Isotope for fancy sorting/filtering effects.  As such, the elements within the component are positioned absolutely.  This causes problems with the tabindex since the first element being displayed in the list is not necessarily the next element in the DOM.  Since no tabindex is declared the browser will use the DOM order of the elements which leads to a really poor experience (ex: a button in the 3rd container receives the first focus).  I tried to work around this by declaring an explicit tabindex that is set after Isotope performs its magic - and you'd think it would work, but alas, it seems like (in Chrome and Firefox at least) an explicit tabindex on an element inserted into the DOM is not honored.  In my case, the focus jumps from the element before the dynamic content to the omnibar in Chrome, then down to the explicitly defined tabindex that comes first.  That's a lot to wrap your head around so I put together an [example](https://codepen.io/recursivecodes/pen/rpVdxm).

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="foo">
  <input type="text" id="bar">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>

setTimeout(function(){
  // this element will receive the proper focus
  let x = document.createElement('input');
  x.id = 'biz';
  x.type = 'text';
  x.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
  document.querySelector('#container').append(x);

  // this element will NOT receive focus after #biz
  let y = document.createElement('input');
  y.id = 'baz';
  y.type = 'text';
  y.setAttribute('tabindex', 1);
  document.querySelector('#container').append(y)
}, 500);

document.querySelector('#foo').focus();
```

The first three inputs work fine in that case, but you'll notice that as soon as we get to the input with tabindex of 1 the focus jumps over it and onto the codepen elements.

So what gives?  Certainly there's got to be a workaround here?  I can't be the only one worried about the tabindex of dynamically loaded and absolutely positioned elements?